# Get the latest recorded data from the MS Access database while sending query

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi can anybody tell me how to get the latest data logged in database while sending the query. Like i have MS Access database in which i have logged data along with time-stamping, so when i send a query i should get only the latest information stored in it or get the latest data from it based on the last recorded time.

My access database has the following data:

```
DEVICENAME                   WINDOW           DATE            TIME

Device1                   WIN1          6/10/2013   11:16 AM
Device1                   WIN2          6/10/2013   11:16 AM
Device2                   WIN7          6/10/2013   11:16 AM
Device2                   WIN7          6/10/2013   11:16 AM
Device1                   WIN1          6/10/2013   11:20 AM
Device1                   WIN2          6/10/2013   11:20 AM
Device1                   WIN3          6/10/2013   11:20 AM
```

As you can see device1 is logged twice @ different intervals, but from these logged data i need only the latest logged data i.e., device1 logged @ 11:20AM. How do i initiate a query for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (assuming you've stored your date and time in the same column):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE datetime = (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM yourTable)
```

### Edit

Based on the query you are using I would go with the following:

```
("SELECT window, Time FROM ErrorLog where DEVICENAME='" + btn[add].Text +"' AND Time = (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM ErrorLog)");
```

Comment: Giraffe: Sir i have a query like this ("select window,Time from ErrorLog where DEVICENAME='" + btn[add].Text + "'");

So how do i implement the query u have given?
If i implement this way i get an error:
("select window,SELECT MAX(Time) from ErrorLog where DEVICENAME='" + btn[add].Text + "'");

Comment: Giraffe: Sir i get this error when i implement this query. Cannot have Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object fields in aggregate argument (time).

Comment: What datatype is your Time column?

Comment: Giraffe: Sir its of string type.

Comment: :/ It would have been far better programmatically if you'd made that a DateTime column instead. The reason that code failed is because you can not get a maximum value of a string field.